# Using webStorage to apply CSS by Toggling Class

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-storage

I have a site with 2 button I'm using to toggle between [default] Dark and Light theme. I'm doing this using the `:root` directive, and CSS variables, like so:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    Here is some text
  </div>

  <br/>

  <button type="button" onclick="lightToggle()">Light Theme</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="darkToggle()">Dark Theme</button>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --bg-color-1: #011627;
}

.light {
    --bg-color-1: #fbfbfb;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color-1);
}
```

JS:

```
function lightToggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.add("light");
}

function darkToggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.remove("light");
}
```

This works well for single pages. Now, I would like to have the theme persist when navigating to another webpage within the same domain. I don't want to use cookies, and I don't want to store persistent data on the client side, so I figured `sessionStorage` is most appropriate for this. I've added `setItem` in my HTML and JS, but am having difficulty toggling the `light` class using this `sessionStorage` value (and I'm not even sure this is best practice when using webStorage?). Here is where I'm starting from:

HTML:

```
<script>
  sessionStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");

</script>

<body>
  <div>
    Here is some text
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="lightToggle()">Light Theme</button>

  <button type="button" onclick="darkToggle()">Dark Theme</button>

</body>
```

CSS (unchaged):

```
:root {
    --bg-color-1: #011627;
}

.light {
    --bg-color-1: #fbfbfb;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color-1);
}
```

JS:

```
function lightToggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.add("light");

    sessionStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
}

function darkToggle() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.remove("light");

    sessionStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
}
```

What's the best practice for using webStorage to apply a `class` to the HTML `body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine except for the script that is embedded in html. It will always override your selected theme with 'dark' value. So just change this script to read the current value in session storage and apply the appropriate class.

```
    <script>
      var theme = sessionStorage.getItem("theme");
      var element = document.body;
      
      if(theme && theme === 'light'){
        element.classList.add("light");
      }
      else{
        element.classList.remove("light");
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Actually, this isn't working for me. Do I have to make other adjustments to my JS or HTML? Or does it require localStorage?

Comment: FWIW, this `<script>` tag comes after my `stylesheet` in the HTML header. Not sure why else this might not be working... the solution makes sense, and when I run the commands in `console`, it works.

Might it have something to do with the way the page loads? I'm running jQuery and Bootstrap as well, in case that matters (also loaded before this script tag).

Comment: Placing the `<script>` tag before or after the `stylesheet` will not matter as the class will be applied regardless. The problem here should be that the `script` is defined before the `body` element, hence it will not be able to access `document.body`. Placing it inside the `body` element should make it work.

Comment: Works! Perfect! Sorry for the mixup. Thanks :)